# Trouble interpreting time in a Soseki text passage お前が俺を殺したのは今からちょうど100年前だね

Tags: meaning, time

I just read Natsume Soseki’s *The Third Night* (『第三夜』), and I have trouble understanding well the time in that passage :

> 『お父さん、その杉のねだったね。』
>
> 『うん、そうだ。』と思わず答えてしまった。
>
> 『文化5年辰年だろう。』
>
> なるほど文化5年辰年らしく思われた。
>
> **『お前が俺を殺したのは今からちょうど100年前だね。』**
>
> 自分はこの言葉を聞くや否や、今から100年前文化5年の辰年のこんな暗闇の番に、この杉の根で、一人の目倉を殺したという自覚が、忽然として頭の中に起こった。

Is the kid saying that his father killed him/a man a hundred years ago (point of view from the future) since he’s saying 今からちょうど100年前だ, or that he indeed killed someone else a hundred years ago?

/EDIT/
The English translation in my book says that the father remembers killing a *man* a hundred years ago, while I thought that the kid comes from the future (it’s a dream) and he indeed killed the kid that night. (In the text, he wants to get into that forest in order to abandon him because he’s a burden since he’s blind.)

Comment: How are your two interpretations different in terms of when the killing happened?

Comment: The English translation in my book says that the father remembers killling a man a hundred years ago, while I thought that the kid comes from the future (it’s a dream) and he indeed killed the kid that night. (In the text, he wants to get into that forest in order to abandon him because he’s a burden since he’s blind).

Comment: 明鏡国語辞典の「今から」の項目で「いま‐から【今から】〘副〙
現在を始点として**過去または未来**に向かうさま。「事件は─五年前に起こった」「─でも遅くはない」⇔今まで」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible since all this is happening in the narrator’s dream. The kid might as well have come from the future.

However, there is little ambiguity here. The kid specifically says **今から**ちょうど百年前. It means 100 years before the time of speech, or simply “100 years ago”. The most natural interpretation would be that the father (the dreamer) killed the kid (a blind man) 100 years ago in their respective earlier lives.

This interpretation is backed up by facts. 文化五年 is year 1808, and 夢十夜 was first published in 1908.